# javascript recursion problem with a function that calles itself multiple times

Tags: javascript, minesweeper

I have 2 tables one above each other,  and the one below have every cell Id something like "colxrowy"and the above one "OverColxrowy" where x and y are numbers.
I created the function from above that should clear the background color on the cells from the table from above if there is nothing on the table below, but it never passes first if. What should I do?

```js
function clearBlankAround(cellId) {
  var col=0,row=0;
  col=cellId.charAt(3);
  row=cellId.charAt(7);
  document.getElementById("OverCol"+col+"row"+row).style.backgroundColor="";
  cell00 = document.getElementById("col" + (col - 1) + "row" + (row - 1));
  cell01 = document.getElementById("col" + col       + "row" + (row - 1));
  cell02 = document.getElementById("col" + (col + 1) + "row" + (row - 1));
  cell10 = document.getElementById("col" + (col - 1) + "row" + row);
  cell12 = document.getElementById("col" + (col + 1) + "row" + row);
  cell20 = document.getElementById("col" + (col - 1) + "row" + (row + 1));
  cell21 = document.getElementById("col" + col       + "row" + (row + 1));
  cell22 = document.getElementById("col" + (col + 1) + "row" + (row + 1));
  var x=0;z=0;
  
  for(x=-1;x<2;x++)
  for(z=-1;z<2;z++)
    if(document.getElementById("OverCol"+(col+x)+"row"+(row+z)))
      document.getElementById("OverCol"+(col+x)+"row"+(row+z)).style.backgroundColor=""

  if(cell00&&cell00.innerHTML=="")  clearBlankAround(cell00.id) //"first if"
  if(cell01&&cell01.innerHTML=="")  clearBlankAround(cell01.id)
  if(cell02&&cell02.innerHTML=="")  clearBlankAround(cell02.id)
  if(cell10&&cell10.innerHTML=="")  clearBlankAround(cell10.id)
  if(cell12&&cell12.innerHTML=="")  clearBlankAround(cell12.id)
  if(cell20&&cell20.innerHTML=="")  clearBlankAround(cell20.id)
  if(cell21&&cell21.innerHTML=="")  clearBlankAround(cell21.id)
  if(cell22&&cell22.innerHTML=="")  clearBlankAround(cell22.id)
}
```

Comment: What do you mean that it never gets past the first `if`? It never recurses at all? Only the first if doesn't work?

Comment: @samuei only the first if from that train of if gets executed, the rest get ignored

Comment: Please provide enough html to generate a runnable [mcve] and give us a more detailed explanation of how the function shown needs to work. There is most likely a far simpler approach to this

Comment: So there is one error on your page - you are reading col and row as strings, not numbers.  Under these circumstances JS can be weird: "1"+1 = "11", whereas "1"-1=0.  Always best to convert to a number - it is possible this is related to your problem. Use parseInt to convert string to int.

Comment: I would assume your first condition is always met and you are now stuck in a loop, as you start the function again. I cannot see you changing the innnerHTML value.... Also do you want the condition to not equal blank, so you can clear "!=" instead of "=="

Comment: @charlietfl here it is the full page: https://codepen.io/florin-baciu-the-typescripter/pen/MWbqxJp

Comment: very bad technique. table cells can be acceded by `.rows[ ]` and `.cells[ ]` methods, and please stop coding in HTML_1, and use  `thead` and `tbody` tags !

Comment: @MisterJojo thank you for the tips , i am a beginner so every tip is welcome

Comment: It seems that the first test condition <code>if(cell00&&cell00.innerHTML=="") </code> is always met so your code enters a dead-end loop.
It seems that the series of 8 tests must be taken out of the function, which, btw, does not seem to have a valid reason to be recurring.

Comment: I made an answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66099102/javascript-minesweeper-opening-whole-mine-free-area-at-once-not-working-proper/66539667#66539667, this look like a  similar question?