# Outer grid in Mine Sweeper game bugged condition

Tags: javascript, for-loop, if-statement, game-development, minesweeper

I'm trying to replicate in Js the old Mine Sweeper game. But I'm stuck declaring conditions to the blue grid (that is distant 2 numbers from the bomb at the center of it); I have 2 bugged cells appearing on the other side when a bomb is on the grid left/right border.
[image]

(In the conditions you can see comments with numbers referring to 50 bomb position to help locate better which condition does what, hope it helps)

Thanks a lot for help me, I'm a student :)

```
let   gridLength = Math.sqrt(numbOfCells);
const cellNumb   = Number(singleCell.textContent);

const atRightSide = cellNumb % gridLength === 0;
const atLeftSide  = (cellNumb - 1) % gridLength === 0;

const twoRightSide = cellNumb % gridLength === 0 
                   || (cellNumb + 1) % gridLength === 0;

//check 9+10 nums and 10 multiplies
const twoLeftSide = (cellNumb - 1) % gridLength === 0 
                  || (cellNumb) % gridLength === 2;

// check 1+10 nums and 2+10 nums

if (bombsArray.includes(cellNumb)) {
    singleCell.classList.add('bomb')

   //  this create green cells
} else if ( !atLeftSide && bombsArray.includes(cellNumb - 1)
         || !atRightSide && bombsArray.includes(cellNumb + 1)
         || bombsArray.includes(cellNumb - gridLength)
         || bombsArray.includes(cellNumb + gridLength)
         || !atLeftSide && bombsArray.includes(cellNumb - gridLength - 1)
         || !atRightSide && bombsArray.includes(cellNumb - gridLength + 1)
         || !atLeftSide && bombsArray.includes(cellNumb + gridLength - 1)
         || !atRightSide && bombsArray.includes(cellNumb + gridLength + 1)
        ) {

    singleCell.classList.add('green');
    singleCell.addEventListener('click', function () {
         addGreenPoints()
    })

    //  this create blue cells (example 55)

        } else if (
            !twoLeftSide && bombsArray.includes(cellNumb - 2)
            // 53
            || !twoRightSide && bombsArray.includes(cellNumb + 2)
            // 57
            //left and right blue cell

            || bombsArray.includes(cellNumb - (gridLength * 2))
            || bombsArray.includes(cellNumb + (gridLength * 2))
            // these are the top/bottom blue cells

            || !twoLeftSide && bombsArray.includes(cellNumb - (gridLength * 2) - 2)
            // ↖↖  (33)

            // ----------- I think these are the bugged ones
            || bombsArray.includes(cellNumb - (gridLength * 2) - 1)
            //  34
            || bombsArray.includes(cellNumb - (gridLength * 2) + 1)
            // ↗ 36
            || bombsArray.includes(cellNumb + (gridLength * 2) + 1)
            // ➡  76
            || bombsArray.includes(cellNumb + (gridLength * 2) - 1)
            // ⬅ 74 
            // -----------

            || !twoRightSide && bombsArray.includes(cellNumb - (gridLength * 2) + 2)
            // ↗↗ 37
            || !twoRightSide && bombsArray.includes(cellNumb - gridLength + 2)
            // ➡ 47
            || !twoRightSide && bombsArray.includes(cellNumb + gridLength + 2)
            // ↘ 67
            || !twoRightSide && bombsArray.includes(cellNumb + (gridLength * 2) + 2)
            // ↘↘ 77
            || !twoLeftSide && bombsArray.includes(cellNumb + (gridLength * 2) - 2)
            // ↙↙ 73
            || !twoLeftSide && bombsArray.includes(cellNumb + gridLength - 2)
            // ⬅  63
            || !twoLeftSide && bombsArray.includes(cellNumb - gridLength - 2)
            // ⬅ 43

        ) {

            singleCell.classList.add('blue');
            singleCell.addEventListener('click', function () {
                addBluePoints()
            })

        }
```

I think I have these conditions that are useful when generating normal numbs cells, but at borders they create the bugged cells. I tried adding my condition !twoRightSide/!twoLeftSide at these, but I got removed also good cells,  as you can see here: [image].

```
  || bombsArray.includes(cellNumb - (gridLength * 2) - 1)
  || bombsArray.includes(cellNumb - (gridLength * 2) + 1)
  || bombsArray.includes(cellNumb + (gridLength * 2) + 1)
  || bombsArray.includes(cellNumb + (gridLength * 2) - 1)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+nearest+OR+closest+date+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Answer (score 1):

the idea of colors is interesting, but your entire algorithmic approach needs to be reviewed.

I also use the marking of lines in single values as you did to indicate the mine "50", but your first mistake is to start your numbering from the value `1`. You must start from the value `0`.

So you can easily know the coordinates (x,y)
In the case of mine "50" it is actually in position `49`
and the calculation of coordinates becomes:

```
const
  grid_columns = 10  // horizontals positions count
, grid_rows    = 10  // verticals  positions count
  ;
function getMinePosition( mine_position )
  {
  let
    x = mine_position % grid_columns        // horizontal  position 
  , y = (mine_position - x) / grid_columns  // vertical  position
    ;
  return ({x,y})
  }
function getMineAbsolutePosition ({x,y})
  {
  return x + (y * grid_colluns)
  }

console.log( getMinePosition(49) ),                 // -> {x:9,y:4}
console.log( getMineAbsolutePosition({x:9,y:4}) ),  // -> 49
```

to check the presence of a mine near a square, you must 1 check the 8 surrounding squares,
whose coordinates are:

```
const proxi1 =
  [ {h:-1,v:-1}, {h: 0,v:-1}, {h:+1,v:-1}, {h:-1,v: 0}
  , {h:+1,v: 0}, {h:-1,v:+1}, {h: 0,v:+1}, {h:+1,v:+1} ]
```

for example `{h:0,v:-1}` gives the position above a box and `{h:-1,v:-1}` that below on the left.

if you use `{h:+1,v:0}` on the coordinates `{x,y}` returned by
`getMinePosition(19)` --> `{x:9,y:4}` + `{h:+1,v:0}` = `{x:10,y:4}` does not exist because `x:10` is `>= grid_colluns`

Which leads you to this kind of solution:

```js
const
  minesArea = document.querySelector('table')
, gridSize  = { Rows:10, Cols:10 }
, getXY = pos =>
  {
  let
    x = pos % gridSize.Cols       // horizontal  position 
  , y = (pos - x) / gridSize.Cols // vertical  position
    ;
  return ({x,y})
  }
, proxi1_green =
  [ {h:-1,v:-1}, {h: 0,v:-1}, {h:+1,v:-1}, {h:-1,v: 0}
  , {h:+1,v: 0}, {h:-1,v:+1}, {h: 0,v:+1}, {h:+1,v:+1} ] 
, proxi2_blue =
  [ {h:-2,v:-2}, {h:-1,v:-2}, {h: 0,v:-2}, {h:+1,v:-2}, {h:+2,v:-2} 
  , {h:-2,v:-1}, {h:-2,v: 0}, {h:-2,v:+1}
  , {h:+2,v:-1}, {h:+2,v: 0}, {h:+2,v:+1}
  , {h:-2,v:+2}, {h:-1,v:+2}, {h: 0,v:+2}, {h:+1,v:+2}, {h:+2,v:+2}  ]
  ;
draw_Grid();
setColors( 49 );

function draw_Grid()
  {
  let rx;
  for(let r = gridSize.Rows; r--;)
    {
    rx = minesArea.insertRow();
    for(let c = gridSize.Cols; c--;)
      rx.insertCell();
    }    
  }
function setColors( posM )
  {
  let {x,y} = getXY(posM);
  minesArea.rows[y].cells[x].className = 'red';

  setProxiColor( proxi1_green, 'green' );
  setProxiColor( proxi2_blue, 'blue' );

  function setProxiColor( proxi, color )
    {
    let _x,_y;
    for (let {h,v} of proxi )
      {
      _x = x + h;
      _y = y + v;
      if ( _x < 0 || _x >= gridSize.Cols
        || _y < 0 || _y >= gridSize.rows 
        ) 
        continue;
      minesArea.rows[_y].cells[_x].className = color;
      };
    }
  }
```

```css
table {
  --szCellsWH   : 16px;
  margin           : 0 auto;
  font-size        : var(--szCellsWH);
  border-collapse  : separate;
  border-spacing   : 1px;
  background-color : #494b4d ; /*   var(--cSubText);  */
  }
td {
  width      : var(--szCellsWH);
  min-width  : var(--szCellsWH);
  height     : var(--szCellsWH);
  min-height : var(--szCellsWH);
  background : #808080;
  }
.blue  { background-color: #87cefa; }
.green { background-color: #adff2f; }
.red   { background-color: #ff0000; }
```

```html
<table><tbody></tbody></table>
```

[see my solution here (for a "classic" minesweeper game)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66099102/javascript-minesweeper-opening-whole-mine-free-area-at-once-not-working-proper/66539667#66539667)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are creating a lot of complexity by trying to define and compare each cell individually. I would recommend using a two-dimensional array to represent the grid. Then you can use `for` loops to loop through the rows and columns. In this example I create a 5x5 grid. Each cell has a value of 0.

```js
let grid = [
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
]
```

You can set one cell directly using

```js
grid[2,2] = 1    // third row, third column is now 1
```

If you want to also set the surrounding cells to 1 you can create a for loop that loops through the rows and columns. You can use a `clamp` function to prevent selecting cells that are outside the grid.

For example:

```js
function showCells(x, y) {
  // start to the left and end to the right of the selected cell
  let startrow = y - 1
  let endrow = y + 1
  let startcol = x - 1
  let endcol = x + 1

  // make sure the position cant be smaller than 0 or bigger than the grid
  startrow = clamp(startrow, 0, grid.length - 1)
  endrow = clamp(endrow, 0, grid.length - 1)
  startcol = clamp(startcol, 0, grid[0].length - 1)
  endcol = clamp(endcol, 0, grid[0].length - 1)

  // set the position and everything around it to 1
  for (let row = startrow; row <= endrow; row++) {
    for (let col = startcol; col <= endcol; col++) {
      grid[row][col] = 1
    }
  }
}

function clamp(num, min, max) {
  return Math.min(Math.max(num, min), max);
}

showCells(2, 2)
console.log(grid)
```